# handling optional field validation

Tags: marshmallow

I have a simple problem and am unsure the best way to handle it. I have a schema defined as follows:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    title = fields.String(required=True)
    imageUrl = fields.Url()
```

`imageUrl` is an optional field, sometimes it will be None/null. If this happens, it's ok and it doesn't need to be a valid url. But I when I do:

```
my_schema.load(request.get_json())
```

on incoming data that is PUT, the url field records an error: `Field may not be null.`

I thought using `partial=True` in the call to load would work, but it doesn't. I also didn't like that because this isn't a partial, it's the full object, it just so happens some of my fields are nullable in the DB.

How do I get marshmallow to validate the imageUrl when it is non-null, but to ignore it when it is null?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I figured this out now. cdonts answer was close, but wasn't working for me. I did a careful re-read of the docs. `default` is used to provide a default value for missing values during **serialization**.

However I was running in to the issue during **deserialization and validation** time. There are parameters for that too.

A combination of `allow_none` and `missing` was useful in my situation and solved my problem.

Copy from the doc (v3.20.1):

> **allow_none** – Set this to True if None should be considered a valid value during validation/deserialization. If load_default=None and allow_none is unset, will default to True. Otherwise, the default is False.
> https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.fields.html#marshmallow.fields.Field

The missing option is deprecated since 3.13.0 (2021-07-21): https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id11.

Comment: It would help to show some code about how you used `allow_none` and `missing`, and to add a link to the related docs.

Answer (score 5):

I upvoted the answer from @lostdorje since it is the correct one, a code example would be something like:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    field_1 = fields.Str(allow_none=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should provide a default value.

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    title = fields.String(required=True)
    imageUrl = fields.Url(default=None)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work. If a request comes in the imageUrl=None, the default has no effect and validation still fails. If a request comes in with the imageUrl missing completely, then there is no validation error, but the key is not added to the loaded request.

Comment: Your example is invalid. It doesn't work.